# Weak and strong orders

Tags: order-theory

Did I understand it right, that `R={⟨X,Y⟩∣X⊆Y}` is a weak order and `{⟨X,Y⟩∣X⊂Y}` is a strong order (not sure about the correct english term)?

Comment: What do you mean by weak and strong order?

Comment: This is what I understand as a weak order: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering

Answer (score 0):

Well, I assume, you mean $(X,Y) ∈ R$ iff $X⊂Y$ or $X=Y$. Let us further assume that $⊆$ is a partial order relation, while $⊂$ is irreflexive ($∀X:X\not⊂X$). Then $⊂$ is called “strict (partial) order“ and $⊆$ is a reflexive (partial) order relation. Wikipedia calls it also [weak partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Strict_and_non-strict_partial_orders). Because of the duality between sets of pairs and binary relations you can consider the two sets defined above as binary relations that are equivalent to the corresponding defining relations.

I just saw that you link to strict weak order relations in the comments. If you are sure that this is the right definition then you the answer is probably: „No.“ (depending on the missing definition of $⊆$ and $⊂$).

Answer (score 0):

The subset relation $\subseteq$ is a partial order (*Halbordnung*), and the proper subset relation $\subset$ is a strict partial order (*strenge Halbordnung*). If the underlying set has at least three elements, $\subset$ is not a [strict weak order](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strenge_schwache_Ordnung): if $a,b$, and $c$ are distinct elements, $\{a\}$ is not comparable with $\{b\}$, and $\{b\}$ is not comparable with $\{a,c\}$, but $\{a\}\subset\{a,c\}$, so incomparability with respect to $\subset$ is not an equivalence relation. For essentially the same reason $\subseteq$ is not in general a non-strict weak order (also known as a total preorder or preference relation; German seems to have at least *Präferenzrelation*, *Präferenzordnung*, and *totale Quasiordnung* as possible terms for this concept).